# How to solve Linux If-Else statement syntax error?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I am trying to check whether a directory already exists or not inside a case-control statement. But it is giving an error in **'then'** statement.

```
case $choice in
1)echo "Enter directory name: "
  read dname
  mkdir $dname
  if[-d "$dname"]
  then
     echo "$dname directory already exists."
  else
     echo "$dname directory successfully created."
  fi
  read
  ;;
```

error message:

```
uan.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
uan.sh: line 13: `  then'
```

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points out common problems like these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser is seeing `then` outside of an `if` statement, because you don't have the keyword `if` in a command position. You have the word `if[-d` which the parser accepts as an ordinary command name; the parser doesn't  know or care whether the command actually exists or not.

Whitespace is important:

```
if [ -d "$dname" ]
```

The brackets are supposed to remind you of syntax, but have probably caused more trouble than they have ever saved. `[` is the command, and it requires `]` as its final argument. Using the name `test` is much simpler and doesn't lull you into thinking the brackets are somehow special to the parser:

```
if test -d "$dname"
```